# Помогите разобраться почему не работает модуль в ФормаДокумента МатериалыЦенаПриИзменении(Элемент)

Tags: 1с, модули

Работаю с 1С: Предприятие 8.3 Практическое пособие разработчика. Только начинаю изучение этой программы и этого странного языка. Возникла такая проблема (до этого тоже возникало куча проблем и несовпадений кода из пособия и действительности, но до сих пор получалось все исправлять) - 1 модуль на скриншоте почему то не работает, хотя второй почему то да. Задача: при изменении пункта Цена или Количество в Документах изменять Сумму по формуле "Цена * Количество = Сумма". Второй модуль на скриншоте был создан раньше и, возможно, проблема в этом, но почему то думается, что дело не в этом. Помогите решить эту проблему, а так же можете дать мне советы о том, что мне нужно знать об языке 1С. Ответы со скриншотами, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приводите программу текстом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У документа должна быть определена "Форма документа" - проверьте, если она не создана, то создайте и выберите ее по умолчанию (у меня на скрине их две, у вас возможно будет одна "ФормаДокумента"). Т.е. мы говорим 1с какую форму хотим показывать пользователю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форме документа (та которую выбрали по умолчанию) расположена табличная часть "Материалы", в которой есть колонки "Количество", "Цена" и т.д. Проверьте свойство "ПриИзменении" для каждой колонки (Количество и Цена). В этом свойстве указывается какая процедура будет вызвана при изменении значения.

Например для колонки "Цена" должно быть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы посмотреть свойства колонки табличной части Материалы, выделите нужную колонку и правой клавишей выбираем свойства, откроется справа окно, там и смотрите.

Еще проверь свойство общего модуля РаботаСДокументами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Если предложенное решение Вам помогло, то отметьте его галочкой пожалуйста. Таким образом Вы повысите свою и мою репутацию на сайте. Это даст нам больше возможностей. Спасибо.*

Answer (score 0):

Вы не предоставили код общего модуля РаботаСДокументами.РассчитатьСумма() без него трудно предположить что там происходит, телепатией не обладаю к сожалению.

Но, можете попробовать сделать так:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура МатериалыЦенаПриИзменении(Элемент)
    СтрокаТабличнойЧасти = Элементы.Материалы.ТекущиеДанные;
    // РаботаСДокументами.РассчитатьСумма(СтрокаТабличнойЧасти);
    
    СтрокаТабличнойЧасти.Сумма = СтрокаТабличнойЧасти.Количество * СтрокаТабличнойЧасти.Цена;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Проверьте, чтобы названия реквизитов таб. части совпадало с вашими.
Если этот вариант будет работать, то разбирайтесь с общим модулем РаботаСДокументами, что-то в нем не так. Возможно тело процедуры общего модуля вообще пустое.
Если предложенное решение Вам помогло, то отметьте его галочкой пожалуйста. Таким образом Вы повысите свою и мою репутацию на сайте. Это даст нам больше возможностей. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавил скрин общего модуля, попробовал то, что вы сказали - пока ничего не получается. Да вообще ничего не получается теперь) Даже от количества сумма не меняется

Comment: Вижу, с общим модулем нет проблем, все должно работать.. Сделал еще один ответ, читайте выше.